# if-else statement only works in a specific order and I don't know why

Tags: c++, if-statement

I recently started learning how to program and one of the tasks I was assigned was to write an algorithm in c++ that would ask for three numbers, then pick out the smallest one. A segment of the code I wrote is as follows.

```
if (a <= b) { a = d; }
else { b = d; }
```

This is supposed to pick out the smallest of the first two numbers and then "link it" to `d`, but after a while of getting the wrong results I realized that regardless of the values of `a` and `b` it gives `d` a value of `0`.
Turns out this only works if I write the same thing with the characters flipped, with the input variables coming last:

```
 if (a <= b) { d = a; }
 else { d = b; }
```

Why is that? Is there something about the syntax of c++ that I should know?

Seems like a strangely specific rule to have...

EDIT: I accidentally wrote {a = d} instead of {d = a} when writing this post, it should as I intended now.

Here's the rest of the code (it works, but only after flipping the characters as I said earlier)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a,b,c,d,min;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    if (a<=b) {d = a;}
    else {d = b;}
    if (c<=d) {min = c;}
    else {min = d;}
    cout << min << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: You wrote `a = d;`. It sounds like you want `d = a;`

Comment: The `=` operator performs assignment - `a = d;` assigns a value to the left-hand side. So in your first example, you're changing the value of `a` to the value of `d`, which if you haven't already given it a value, might be getting initialized to 0. In your second example, you're changing the value of `d`, which is what I suspect you want.

Comment: "_Seems like a strangly specific rule to have_" Welcome to most of programming.

Comment: In c++ assignment copies the value from one object to the other. It does not declare a relationship between the objects as you would expect form seeing the same thing in a mathematical context. In other words, if `x = y;`, `x` has the value that `y` had at the time of the assignment and any further change to `y` will not impact `x` in any way. In addition, assignment always occurs right to left. The object on the left takes on the value of the object on the right.

Comment: What you need to know is not syntax related, and it isn't specific to C++, it applies to all general purpose programming languages.  Specifically, assignment is not a "link it" operation.  (Indirection can confuse this, especially in languages like C# and Java where the indirection is hidden... but assignment is still making a copy of the value, not linking two variables together)

Comment: @ClaireNielsen "_which if you haven't already given it a value, might be getting initialized to 0_" Not, not really. If the value is not in global scope (as is in this case), and you didn't initialize it (or assign a value to it) yourself, it isn't initialize, and, hence, contain indeterminate value. If you are getting 0 in one particular case, you are getting "lucky", and shouldn't count on it always behaving like this.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks for the replies :)

Comment: C++ uses value semantics on assignment, by default.  Where `d` and `a` are of type `int`,  the assignment `d = a` assigns `d` the value of `a`.  It does not establish a "link" between the two variables.    You have presumably used some other language that supports reference semantics by default, in which case `d = a` would cause `d` to be a reference to `a`.    Don't assume such things carry across between programming languages - they do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code fragment, you are not assigning to d at all. Assignment (=) operator assigns the rvalue (right hand side) to the lvalue (left hand side).  This is very standard syntax.